# Sails+Passport: Logging out won't work

Tags: node.js, sails.js, passport.js

I'm making an app that authenticates users with Facebook.
I'm so new to both Sails and Passport so I decided follow this repository: https://github.com/stefanbuck/sails-social-auth-example

I followed this repository faithfully and was able to make login function with facebook so easily, but logout function won't work.

In routes.js is:

```
'/logout' : {
  controller : 'auth',
  action     : 'logout'
}
```

and in AuthController.js is:

```
logout: function (req, res) {
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/');
}
```

When I stopped the server lifting, logout seems to be done, and next time I execute command `sails lift`, it warn me that:

```
warn: handshake error No cookie transmitted with socket.io connection.  Are you trying to access your Sails.js server via socket.io on a 3rd party domain?  If you're ok with losing users' session data, you can set `authorization: false` to disable cookie-checking.  Or you can send a JSONP request first from the client to the Sails.js server to get the cookie (be sure it's the same domain!!)
```

which I don't understand how to handle with.

Would you tell me what is wrong and how I can make it work?

- Sails v0.0.4
- Passport v0.3.4
- passport-facebook v1.0.0

Comment: you may try destroy session object first; `req.session.destroy` then in callback you can redirect. `res.redirect`.

Answer (score 1):

I used Passport with Sails also, my routes.js has logout as a "post"

```
'post /logout':{
    controller: 'user',
    action: 'logout'
},
```

and my logout function is the same, may fix your issue?

Here is my view call also if it's helpful:

```
<form action="/logout" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Log Out"/>
</form>
```